# How to tile vertically only selected windows in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, portable

many applications are open on my Windows XP desktop but i just want tiles 2 windows vertically.

I need portable freeware.

Comment: In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed, click on the 2 taskbar buttons for the applications you want to tile (so the 2 buttons are selected), right-click and choose "Tile vertically" from the popup menu.

No need for an extra application, it's built in Windows!

Comment: oh. I wasn't aware that

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to minimize all windows except the 2 (or more) you want tiled, then do the Tile Windows Vertically